# How to search an array of objects using another array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this

```
[
  {
    "prop1": "value1",
    "prop2": "value1",
    "check": {
      "gender": ['male'],
      "office": ['London','New York']
    }
  },
  {
    "prop1": "value2",
    "prop2": "value2",
    "check": {
      "gender": ['female'],
      "office": ['Berlin', 'New York']
    }
  }
]
```

I want to search this array passing another object, that will be compared to the check property of the array. So, if I search using this object

```
{
  "office": ['New York']
}
```

I will get back both elements of the above array, but if I search using this one

```
{
  "gender": ['male'],
  "office": ['London']
}
```

this will return the first element only. I want also to be able to pass something like

```
{
  "gender": ['female'],
  "office": ['London', 'Berlin'] // <- 2 elements here
}
```

and get back the second element. I can check if the objects are the same but I don't know how to do a partial search, how can I do that?

Comment: Could you show us your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the data
- Check if [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) key has [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) value including ([`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)) in the data `check` array

```js
const data = [{"prop1": "value1", "prop2": "value1", "check": {"gender": ['male'], "office": ['London','New York'] } }, {"prop1": "value2", "prop2": "value2", "check": {"gender": ['female'], "office": ['Berlin', 'New York'] } } ];

const filters = {
  "office": ['Berlin']
}

const customFilter = (data, filters) => {
    const fKeys = Object.keys(filters);
    return data.filter(o =>
        fKeys.every(k => (
            filters[k].some(fVal =>
                o.check[k].includes(fVal)
            )
        ))
    );
};

// Without indentations
// return data.filter(o => fKeys.every(k => filters[k].some(fVal => o.check[k].includes(fVal))));


const result = customFilter(data, filters);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You actually need `filters[k].some(...` to satisfy the OPs last example

Answer (score 0):

```
const searchIn = (data, search) => data.filter(value => {
  const arr = Object.entries(search).filter(([key, data]) => {
    return value.check[key].some(a => data.includes(a))
  })
  return arr.length
})
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.